# Can I declare a function or a struct which can take different types?

Tags: rust

I want to write a function that calls an API and just takes the endpoint as a &str and the data which it should put in the body, my function looks like this:

```
async fn call_clientd<T>(query : &str, json : &T) -> Result<ResBody, reqwest::Error>
where T  : serde::ser::Serialize + ?Sized
{
    let res = Client::new()
        .post(format!("{}{}", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", query))
        .json(json)
        .send()
        .await?;
   let res : ResBody = res.json().await?;
   Ok(res)
}
```

And I need to call it with a String and a u64 :

```
let (res, raw) = match &args.command {
        Commands::Info { raw } => {
            (call_clientd("info", ""), raw)
        },
        Commands::Pending {raw} => {
            (call_clientd("pending", ""), raw)
        },
        Commands::Spend {amount, raw} => {
            (call_clientd("spend", amount), raw)
        },
        Commands::Reissue {coins, raw, validate} => {
            (call_clientd("reissue", coins), raw)
        },
        Commands::Events { raw} => {
            (call_clientd("events", ""), raw)
        },
    };
```

But the compiler always infers (in this case) the function takes a `&str*`... Is there any possible way to do this? My alternative is very redundant.

The error I get seems to have the match arm as an issue rather than the function itself (didn't see that before):

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
   --> mint-client/src/bin/client-cli/main.rs:64:13
    |
56  |       let (res, raw) = match &args.command {
    |  ______________________-
57  | |         Commands::Info { raw } => {
58  | |             (call_clientd("info", ""), raw)
    | |             ------------------------------- this is found to be of type `(impl Future<Output = Result<ResBody, reqwest::Error>>, &bool)`
59  | |         },
60  | |         Commands::Pending {raw} => {
61  | |             (call_clientd("pending", ""), raw)
    | |             ---------------------------------- this is found to be of type `(impl Future<Output = Result<ResBody, reqwest::Error>>, &bool)`
...   |
64  | |             (call_clientd("spend", amount), raw)
    | |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `str`, found `u64`
...   |
71  | |         },
72  | |     };
    | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
    |
```

Comment: Maybe use a union type for your argument ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit I'm very new to Rust, nevery rly heard of unions but will look into that thank you

Comment: If the compiler infers a string for the function parameter type, you're probably giving it one. If you have trouble with the inferred types, you could explicitly specify the type of `T` with `call_clientd::<(String, u64)>(…)` and see if you can learn anything from the resulting type errors.

Comment: It's a C feature but accessible in Rust https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html

Comment: Why would you use a union when you could use an enum? I'm not sure that's the best solution here anyway. It would be useful to see your error message, @NicoLS, and also to see what the error is if you try manually specifying the type parameters as Caesar said

Comment: @Caesar That would be `call_clientd::<u64>(…)`.

Comment: Yes I looked into unions, I don't think this would be good since I would have to use unsafe to get to the data and I d like to avoid calling any unsafe code @Peterrabbit

Comment: @canton7 I update the question with the error

Comment: It should work if you use `call_clientd(…).await`

Comment: @Caesar yes its because in the first match arm I give a &str to the function and then I get the error when I try to use it with u64 in another arm...But I thought if I use a generic type with trait bounds in the declaration this should be fine..

Comment: @Jmb do you want to post it as answer so I can tag it as the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `call_clientd` is an `async` function, which means that it really returns some opaque type that implements `Future<Output = Result<ResBody, reqwest::Error>>`. When you use different type parameters for `call_clientd`, you get different (incompatible) returned futures.

The part of the error that says "expected `str`, found `u64`" is a bit misleading: the compiler saw that the first match arm returned the future for `call_clientd::<str>` so it's telling you that it wants the same future and instead found the future for `call_clientd::<u64>`.

Since it is very unlikely that you want the future itself, you can simply `await` it to get the underlying `Result<ResBody, reqwest::Error>`:

```
let (res, raw) = match &args.command {
        Commands::Info { raw } => {
            (call_clientd("info", "").await, raw)
        },
        Commands::Pending {raw} => {
            (call_clientd("pending", "").await, raw)
        },
        Commands::Spend {amount, raw} => {
            (call_clientd("spend", amount).await, raw)
        },
        Commands::Reissue {coins, raw, validate} => {
            (call_clientd("reissue", coins).await, raw)
        },
        Commands::Events { raw} => {
            (call_clientd("events", "").await, raw)
        },
    };
```

Comment: This is [issue #65442](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65442).